# What does the "n copies of type type" mean by OpenGL core profile

Tags: opengl

I'm looking at [OpenGL 4.6 core profile](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf). In chapter 23 table 23.12 it writes

```
Get value                  |    Type     |   Get Command  | Initial value |
TEXTURE_BINDING_BUFFER     |   80* x Z^+ |   GetIntegerv  |      0        |
```

and table 23.1 explain type code

> *Z^+* is Non-negative integer or enumerated value
>
> *n × type* is n copies of type *type* (n∗ indicates n is minimum)

But [OpenGL 4 Reference Pages](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/) writes glGetIntegerv will return **a single value** for this enumerator. It seems like that type *80 x Z^+* or *Z^+* makes no difference. So I think I do not quite understand the table 23.1's explanation about "n x type", can anyone explain this for me? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The state vector for this get enumerator consists of `80*` values. However, an individual `glGetIntegerv` for this enumerator only returns one of those values. Specifically, the one for the currently active texture unit, as defined by a call to `glActiveTexture`.

The specification defines how this works in section 22.5. You can also use `glGetIntegeri_v` to select from a specific texture unit, as also specified in 22.5.

Basically, you can't *just* use the state table to know how a particular get call works.

Comment: I think you totally solve my question. I add a comment for I find a may **not so meaningful** but related question when read specification again. In Chapter 8, it writes the `glActiveTexture` will get an error `INVALID_ENUM`  if actived texture units exceed `MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS`. Above constant explained in 11.1.3.5 is sum of 6 other constants. They are all implementation-dependent, and each constant has min value 16 in chapter 23. So the min `MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS` will be 96. Why do they not set `96*` for `TEXTURE_BINDING_BUFFER` to match the min texture units number

Comment: @uuutty: "*So the min `MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS` will be 96.*" Not according to the actual table; it's listed as 80. The minimum *was* 96 in GL 4.3 (presumably due to compute shaders), but they reduced it to 80 in GL 4.4.

Comment: what would the 6th stage be? there are only 5, and 5*16 is 80

Comment: @derhass: Vertex, TCS, TES, GS, FS, and Compute.